# Can't tell what the numbers mean on my y-axis scatterplot in Python

Tags: python, scatter-plot, yaxis

My study is about Coronavirus cases in the United States. The state population is on my y-axis, and the deaths-to-case ratio is on my x-axis. For whatever reason, my x-axis goes in increments of .5 up to 4.0 - this means that it's not going by millions, because for example, California has 39M residents. But I can't figure out what the logic is with this y-axis numbering. Screenshot is attached.[image]

```
sns.scatterplot(x='deaths_to_cases', y='StatePopulation', data=df)
```

Comment: It will be hard to help without looking at your dataframe or the code/data that creates it.

Comment: It's from this site, scroll down and its the 'States Current Values' CSV. https://covidtracking.com/api